# Scaling by x and y force d3js trouble

Tags: d3.js

I have trouble with scaling by x and y when drag any node. Does anyone have the same trouble?

There are lines which used for force:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, defaultParams.maxX])
        .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, defaultParams.maxY])
        .range([height, 0]);


var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([defaultParams.maxX, defaultParams.maxY])
        .charge(-400)
        .linkDistance(5)
        .on("tick", tick);


function tick() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.source.x); })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.source.y); })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.target.x); })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.target.y); });

        node
            .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })

}

function dragMove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "trouble"? Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please? Your code doesn't tell us where `dragMove` is actually used.

Comment: You don't need to use the scales to set the positions of the nodes and edges. The force layout uses it's size to compute the position of the nodes.

Comment: So, you mean that I should on move do something like this?

d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:
drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", dragMove);

and force.call(drag);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LmN7F/1/ here you can see not correct coordinates for "setosa 15000", when drag it

Comment: So your question is about updating the text label, not about the scales?